# MozTransform and WebkitTransform: what's now the relative code for IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, webkit, internet-explorer-9

If for Safari and Chrome:

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg) translate(0, 340px);

elem.style.MozTransform = '  rotate('+count+'deg)';
```

and for FF:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(135deg) translate(0, 340px);

elem.style.WebkitTransform = '  rotate('+count+'deg)';
```

what the code for Ie9?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
-ms-transform: rotate(1deg); -ms-transform-origin: top left;
```